# Cannot connect to a localhost. Is it client or localhost issue?

Tags: c#, sockets, visual-studio-2013, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am trying to create a thread, which keeps a listener alive at 127.0.0.1. I am  using the following code to create the listener:

```
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"); //Localhost Ip Address
        TcpListener connectionListner = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 2003); 
        connectedSocket = connectionListner.AcceptSocket();
        connectionListner.Start();
```

***I am facing the problem at the client-side.*** When I try to connect a client to the above-created localhost (separate program), I get an error.

**Client Code:**

```
class Client
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("client has started." + Environment.NewLine);            
        connectToLocalHost();
    }

    static void connectToLocalHost()
    {
        string ipaddress = "127.0.0.1";
        int port = 2003;
        try
        { 
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ipaddress, port);
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            Byte[] data = new Byte[256]; // Buffer to store the response bytes.

            // String to store the response ASCII representation.
            String responseData = String.Empty;

            // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
            Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);

            // Close everything.
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
           }
        catch (SocketException SE)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Socket Error..... " + SE.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:**

> Message = "No connection could be made because the target machine
>   actively refused it 127.0.0.1:2003"

Comment: In the thread that created the listener, you are not calling connectionListener.Start(), which should throw an error when you proceed to call AcceptSocket. Can you post the full thread code ?

Comment: @J.Doe: I am calling `connectionListener.Start()` but at a different point. The localhost side is a tested application and already worked before. I have only written a new client today, which is not working. But still I will update that line in the OP.

Comment: Ji, @skm, before getting the Socket Stream invoke the `connect` method, as the official documentation says: "You must call the Connect method first, or the GetStream method...". Check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to open this port on firewall.

https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html

Comment: My firewall is already disabled still I tried to follow the blog to allow connection on the port 2003...didn't work.